# Similar to how spacetime is the means through which gravity exerts its influence, is there such an entity that allows electromagnetism etc. to do so?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity

Similar to how spacetime is the means through which gravity exerts its influence, is there such a field/ entity through which electromagnetism operates? I got this question while reading 'The Fabric of The Cosmos'

Comment: I don't know what "spacetime is the means through which gravity exerts its influence" is supposed to mean, but see e.g https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76354/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46324/50583 for discussions of similarities and differences between electromagnetism and general relativity

Comment: Spacetime "is to" gravity in at least three ways. We can compare $g_{\mu\nu}$ to $A_\mu$ in one sense, $\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\rho$ to $A_\mu$ [in a different sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_covariant_derivative), and $R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ to $F_{\mu\nu}$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative#Properties) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/182428)).

Comment: Though I can’t give an answer, I believe what you are looking for is that the electromagnetic force is mediated by the exchange of photons, or “particles” of light whose perpendicular electromagnetic fields satisfy Maxwell’s equations. In more formal terms, the photon is the gauge boson for the electromagnetic force.

Answer (score 1):

Spacetime is to gravity as spacetime is to electromagnetism.

The tangent bundle of spacetime is to gravity as a principal $U(1)$ bundle of spacetime is to electromagnetism.

See [another answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/126978/what-is-the-basis-of-gauge-theory/127036#127036) to which @ACuriousMind could have linked.

Comment: The principal bundle in GR is the *frame* bundle, i.e. the bundle of ordered bases of the tangent bundle - the tangent bundle itself is the analogue of the associated bundles in which charged fields in EM live.